# C standard library function to check if a char * is a word?

Tags: c

After reading in a line from a file and splitting that line into tokens, I need to check if the token only contains alphabetic characters [a-zA-Z]. Is there some sort of function in the C Standard Library to check this? I could use regex.h to check this but I think this is overblown.

Sure, I could write a function that loops over the token and checks every char, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

P.S.: Using a third party library is not an option.

Comment: C is minimalistic. "don't want to reinvent" and "a third party library is not an option" does not mix well with each other.

Comment: @J-16 In a real-world project, I would certainly use third-party libraries but this is for an assignment where I am restricted to the Standard Library :-(.

Comment: [s]scanf("%[a-zA-Z]) perhaps?

Comment: @Nyan: unspecified because the scanset contains a hyphen in a location other than first, last, or second-after-`^`. Change that to `%[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]` and it is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certainly:

```
#include <ctype.h>

int isalpha(int ch) // is alphabetic?
int isalnum(int ch) // is alphanumeric?
```

Comment: Obviously you need to iterate this over your char*

Answer (score 3):

You have all these functions defined in `ctype.h`

```
   int isalnum(int c);
   int isalpha(int c);
   int iscntrl(int c);
   int isdigit(int c);
   int isgraph(int c);
   int islower(int c);
   int isprint(int c);
   int ispunct(int c);
   int isspace(int c);
   int isupper(int c);
   int isxdigit(int c);
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated by Kos, `isalpha(int ch)` and `isalnum(int ch)`, but those are not char* functions. Coding your own with isalpha and is alnum should be quite easy, though you must be careful : if you are going to deal with special characters, check your locale (isalpha depends on them).

Comment: +1 For mentioning locale-specific problems (didn't think of that!).

Comment: +1 Yes.  the two functions are only valid for ascii characters.  Some other characters can produce false positives.   You can use isascii to weed them out.

Comment: @Helper Method: If you never call `setlocale()`, then your program will run in the default C locale, where the definition of `isalpha()` is standardised.

Answer (score 3):

[Strspn](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strspn/) will do the job.

The basic concept is that you give it a string, and returns the length of the longest piece that consists of characters in your specific list.
add a-z and A-Z to that list.   If the value back from strspn is the same as the strlen, you are good to go.

Comment: +1 Very nice function and much more flexible than the other posted solutions, though I think I stick with isalpha() (but keep an eye on this).

Comment: This answer is best if you want fixed consistent behavior. Writing your own loop with `isalpha` is an option if you want very very broken locale support. Writing your own loop with `mbrtowc` and `iswalpha` is the only way to get correct locale support.

Answer (score -2):

C Standard Library is very short on char* related functions. Please check this link to see if anythings helps:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/

Comment: Is cplusplus.com full of misinformation really? Can you show some examples?